# Error with proxypass subdomain

Tags: apache-2.4, subdomain, proxypass

I have an Ubuntu Server 14.04 with Apache 2.4.7 and Wildfly 8 installed.
Apache runs in the front and Wildfly in the back. Apache proxies all the apps running on Wildfly.

Now I am trying to proxypass one of my apps from Wildfly with the domain `mysubdomain.example.com`, but I have unwanted side effects. It adds itself to the main domain `example.com/mysubdomain` as well, which is not what I want. First I added this configuration to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysubdomain.example.com
    ServerAlias www.mysubdomain.example.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/myapp/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/myapp/
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I added the same for SSH in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/ssl.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/mysubdomain.mydomain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/mysubdomain.mydomain.key

    ServerName mysubdomain.example.com
    ServerAlias www.mysubdomain.example.com

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/myapp/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/myapp/
</VirtualHost>
```

This configuration does **not work** like this. I was forced to add another configuration in order to make this work. I had to add into `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
<Location "/myapp/">
    ProxyPass "http://localhost:8080/myapp/"
    ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:8080/myapp/"
</Location>
<Location "/myapp">
    ProxyPass "http://localhost:8080/myapp"
    ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:8080/myapp"
</Location>
```

This works (the good thing):

```
http://mysubdomain.example.com
https://mysubdomain.example.com
```

This comes with it (the bad thing):

```
http://example.com/mysubdomain
```

What must I do to only affect the `subdomain` without adding anything to the main domain?

Comment: You need to add conditions on the other vhosts to load only the app wanted.

Comment: Hi @FlorinAsavoaie How would I do that?

Comment: Deny the requests on the other VirtualHosts using mod_rewrite.

Comment: @FlorinAsavoaie Sorry, just noticed big stackoverflow-formatting issues. Quickly repaired them.

Comment: @FlorinAsavoaie Ok, mod_rewrite to deny requests on `example.com/mysubdomain`, but allow them on `mysubdomain.example.com`? Actually, I am happy with the `<VirtualHost ... />`-settings. I just want to get rid of `example.com/mysubdomain`, but keep the rest. How would I do that?